# Kind of like a clock, kind of like a path…

Tags: visual, cipher, pattern, nonogram

<sub>*This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #5: On-and-onograms](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7415/monthly-topic-challenge-5-on-and-onograms)*</sub>

---

**RULES:**

The black footpath (marked by black digits) must be contiguous.

The answer to this "onogram" is a 7 word phrase. To find the phrase, use only the | and - squares found on the 22 3x2 "clocks". The footpath is only for decoration.

[image: onogram]

```
Text version:  
Rows  
                        |   |   -   |   1   |   -
                    -   2   |   -   1   |   2   |
|   -   1   1   -   |   2   1   -   2   -   |   2
        3   |2  1   -   1   1   |   |   |   3   -
                        |   2   |   1   |   -   |
                        |   -   1   -   |   |   -

Columns
        |           |                   |               -       1                       -               1
    -   -           1   |   -           -               1       -           |           |               -
    |   1           |2  1   -           |       |       |   1   -   1       1       1   -   1   |       |
1   1   |   1   1   -   |   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   -   |   |   |   1   |   1   |   1   |   1   1   -
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The final phrase is

> [**The road goes ever on and on**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Goes_Ever_On_(song))

Starting with the nonogram

> We can find the solution easily as long as we remember that the black path must be contiguous
>  [image]
>
>  Now, we can see that there are at most one blue and one yellow square in each 3x2 rectangle. Since these were called "clocks", we can assume that the blue and yellow squares are the clock hands. Furthermore, we should assume that the clock starts with both hands pointing up (with the blue covering the yellow) and identify this with the letter **a**. Then, if we similarly map all of the clock faces to letters (yellow up, blue NE -> b etc. with the yellow moving clockwise each time the blue has gone a full circle), we get the following message:
>  [image]